# How to have an array with objects where the objects can increment and state should be set for certain properties in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, styled-components

First of all, apologies for the long and ugly question title...

I have an array with objects in it. Each object in this array holds data for a form. I loop over this array using .map(), which allows me to create multiple forms which are identical in build up, but have different data. The form elements are in a different array with objects, where each object represents an input field.

Now where I'm stuck is that I don't know how to handle the data, or setting of the state. When a user selects something in a form, it should populate the object in the array with data which is specific to that form. But I don't really know how to do that.

Below is my code.

This component is the parent component of the forms. I'm looping over the data to create a form, which I give the formElements array.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import SectiontWrapper from "../../primitives/section-wrapper";
import SectionHeader from "../../primitives/section-header";
import ExpandableForm from "../../constructs/expandable-form";

const AddStocksSection = () => {
  const [stocks, setStocks] = useState([
    {
      market: "",
      stock: "",
      amount: "",
    },
  ]);
  const formElements = [
    {
      label: "Select a market",
      placeholder: "Select",
      required: true,
      value: "",
      onChange: "",
      disabled: "",
      type: "select",
      options: [
        {
          name: "Select",
          value: "select",
        },
        {
          name: "AEX",
          value: "aex",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: "Select a stock",
      placeholder: "Select",
      required: true,
      value: "",
      onChange: "",
      disabled: "",
      type: "select",
      options: [
        {
          name: "Select",
          value: "select",
        },
        {
          name: "Googl",
          value: "googl",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: "How many do you have",
      placeholder: "100",
      required: true,
      value: "",
      onChange: "",
      disabled: "",
      type: "number",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <SectiontWrapper>
      <SectionHeader>Add some stocks</SectionHeader>
      {stocks.map((stock, i) => (
        <ExpandableForm
          key={i}
          expanded={false}
          formElements={formElements}
          data={stock}
        />
      ))}
    </SectiontWrapper>
  );
};

export default AddStocksSection;
```

Below is my expandable form component. It is a form, which should expand, downsize, depending on the prop it receives.

```
import {
  FormWrapper,
  ButtonGroup,
  FormContainer,
} from "./expandable-form-style";
import ButtonOutlined from "../../primitives/button-outlined";
import ButtonSolid from "../../primitives/button-solid";
import Loader from "../loader";
import getFormElement from "../../../tools/getFormElement";

const ExpandableForm = ({
  submitForm,
  isDisabled,
  formElements,
  isLoading,
  expanded,
}) => {
  return (
    <FormWrapper expanded={expanded}>
      <FormContainer>
        {formElements.map((formElement, i) => {
          const FormElement = getFormElement(formElement.type);
          return (
            <FormElement
              key={i}
              label={formElement.label}
              placeholder={formElement.placeholder}
              value={formElement.value}
              onChange={formElement.onChange}
              disabled={formElement.disabled}
              type={formElement.type}
              options={formElement.options}
            />
          );
        })}
        <ButtonGroup>
          <ButtonOutlined disabled={isLoading} color="venetianRed">
            Skip
          </ButtonOutlined>
          <ButtonSolid
            onClick={null}
            disabled={isLoading || isDisabled}
            color="yellowGreen"
          >
            Add
          </ButtonSolid>
          <ButtonSolid
            onClick={() => submitForm()}
            disabled={isLoading || isDisabled}
            color="royalVessel"
          >
            {isLoading ? <Loader /> : "Next"}
          </ButtonSolid>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </FormContainer>
    </FormWrapper>
  );
};

export default ExpandableForm;
```

I'm hoping my description isn't too vague, but I'm not too sure how too ask what I'm meaning. Below is a small design of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: You would probably be better off having your fields be an object, then looping though the object using `Object.entries(formElements).map()`. Then you can just re-access the object using the current item's key. Does it need to be an array?

Comment: It doesn't have to be an object. I'm trying to explore a variety of different ways. It also works with objects! But how would I then create a state variable for all different form values when a user creates a new form?

Comment: Ah I see where your problem is coming in now. Maybe you would be able to just pass the form elements into your form like `<ExpandableForm><FormElement /></ExpandableForm>` then hide and display [children](https://codeburst.io/a-complete-guide-to-props-children-in-react-c315fab74e7c) in the ExpandableForm element, but still manage state easily in the parent?

Comment: Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding your question. For clarity, it may be easier if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)